# Как сделать pull request в определенную ветку, чтобы он не сливался с другими pull'ами?

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-checkout

Не могу понять как сделать pull request в определенную ветку, чтобы он не сливался с другими pull'ами.

В этой ветке уже находятся несколько разных коммитов. Я сделал форк репозитория. Создал новую ветку и внес изменения, запушил в свой репозиторий. Когда я использую "New pull request" на github'e, [мой pull request](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/pull/11520) сливается с другими. А мне нужно что он был отдельным.

Comment: "мой pull request сливается с другими" - вы что под этим имеете в виду?

Comment: https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/pull/11520 Посмотрите пожалуйста ссылку

Comment: Я отправил всего 1 pull request. Не знаю почему там пишется " wants to merge 46 commits into ..."

Comment: Два хороших ответа, добавить почти нечего. :)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Вы [предлагаете изменения](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/pull/11520) в старую ветку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ваша ветка начинается от ветки `master` в исходном репозитории, а pull request нацелен на `2.0.x`. Ветка `master` с тех пор ушла далеко вперёд.

Поэтому в pull request попали кроме вашего коммита все коммиты от `2.0.x` до `master`.

Если вы вносили изменение в `master`, то и pull request вам надо делать в него же.
<sub>Ну, **обычно**. Исключения бывают, но вы их заметите.</sub>

---

Если вы всё же **предложили куда нужно**, но изначально **применили их не туда**, проблема несколько серьёзнее, но [решается всё ещё довольно просто](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-Git-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5):

```
git rebase --onto 2.0.x master tag-getTitle
```

Перевод:

> Возьми изменения из `tag-GetTitle`, сделанных начиная с `master` и примени их к `2.0.x`.

Произойдёт примерно вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Это опасное действие**, в результате коммит(-ы?) ветки `tag-getTitle` будут **перезаписаны** и просто сделать `git push` уже не получится. Необходимо будет сделать `git push --force`. Поскольку это **ваша** ветка, в которую чужие коммиты не ожидаются, здесь это сделать можно.

Comment: Спасибо. Все сработало

Answer (score 4):

> Создал новую ветку

вероятно, вы создали её аналогичной ветке *master*. а вам надо было создавать её аналогичной той ветке, в которую вы собрались отправлять ваши изменения.

т.е. вместо, например:

```
$ git checkout -b новая-ветка
```

надо было указать «исходную» ветку:

```
$ git checkout -b новая-ветка существующая-ветка
```